# How to convert a color image to black and white

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch an image from the camera by using the **ImagePicker**

```
    final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200,);
```

But while displaying it in the UI we can change it with the **colorBlendMode & color** properties.

```
 Image.memory(uint8listImage, colorBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation, color: Colors.grey),
```

But I'm looking to click an image and save the Image to the DB in a Black and white Color. But how?

Comment: check `ColorFilter.matrix` constructor documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
Image grayscale(Image src) {
  var p = src.getBytes();
  for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i += 4) {
    var l = getLuminanceRgb(p[i], p[i + 1], p[i + 2]);
    p[i] = l;
    p[i + 1] = l;
    p[i + 2] = l;
  }
  return src;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to show it in the UI, I would like the black and white image to be added to DB

Comment: In that case, you can use the function. Please have a look into my answer. I have edited the answer.